# what is the difference between series/dataframe and ndarray?

Tags: pandas, numpy, data-science

`Leaving that they are from two different binaries.`

I know that series/dataframe can hold any data type, and ndarray is also heterogenous data.

And also all the slicing operations of numpy are applicable to series.
Is there any other difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found the answer to my question I asked above. For anyone who needs, here it is from [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#vectorized-operations-and-label-alignment-with-series):

> A key difference between Series and ndarray is that operations between
>   Series automatically align the data based on the label. Thus, you can
>   write computations without giving consideration to whether the Series
>   involved have the same labels.

An example:

```
s[1:] + s[:-1]
```

The result for above would produce NaN for both first and last index.

If a label is not found in one Series or the other, the result will be marked as missing NaN.

Comment: Just to add clarification, here 'label' means 'index' or 'axis labels' of the series object. These labels can be accessed through `series.index`. Alternatively, using `series.keys()` which is an alias for `series.index`.